# How to do broadcast in NeuralNetworks?

Tags: neural-networks

In normal case, we can multiply the tensor by the scalar, vector like this:

```
SeedRandom[42];
data=RandomReal[1,{64,40,30}];
channalAttention=RandomReal[1,64];
blockAttention=RandomReal[1];

data*channalAttention//Dimensions
data*blockAttention//Dimensions
```

But in the neural network it seems that only the tensors of exactly the same shape can be operated.

How to perform broadcast calculations also in neural networks?

---

Notice that `blockAttention` is a tensor stream, not a layer similar to `ElementwiseLayer[a # &]`.

`H` and `W` of tensor stream is variable and cannot be specified directly like `ReplicateLayer[{40,30}]`.

Comment: What `Dimensions` are you expecting to get?